# Css changes are not being implemented properly on any mobile browser when I declare multiple classes (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

First I used only the `.usp-name:before{}` class and everything was working properly both on PC & mobile.

Then I added the rest of the classes that I wanted it's shown in the code below.

```
usp-name:before, .usp-email:before, .usp-title:before, .usp-custom:before, .usp-category:before, .usp-content:before, .usp-captcha:before{
    content:" *";
    color: red;
       position: absolute;
    margin-left: -13px;
    }
```

On pc, everything worked fine every time, but on mobile nothing was being applied anymore.

I deleted cache but it didn't help.

Everything was stuck as if I only used only 1 class, the first one that I've tried.

Then I deleted all the classes except one, not the one that was my first try, but another one.

The changes applied properly on both PC and a different mobile browser, but then again when I tried to add all the other classes that I wanted, it got stuck again like before, using only the class that I initially used this time.

The same exact thing happened with chrome, Mozilla, duckduckgo on mobile.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Oh! And by the way, I'm using WordPress.

Comment: An observation, you are missing the dot before the first usp in the code you have given, also two colons before the before is now standard.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently the issue was time. I checked again after 8 hours and everything was implemented correctly this time